# Swift NSScriptCommand performDefaultImplementation

Tags: macos, swift, applescript

I used this code in Objective C:

```
@implementation KDOrderInfo
  - (id)performDefaultImplementation {
    NSString *theRequest = [self directParameter];
    NSDictionary *arguments = [self evaluatedArguments];
    NSLog(@"arguments = %@ %ld",arguments, [arguments count]);
    NSLog(@"theRequest----> %@",theRequest);
    /*.......
    .....*/
    return @YES
  }
```

This code works OK in Objective C.
I converted this code to Swift code as follows:

```
class OrderInfo : NSScriptCommand {
  override func performDefaultImplementation() -> AnyObject! {
    let theRequest: AnyObject! = self.directParameter
    let arguments = self.evaluatedArguments
    println("arguments = \(arguments) argumentsCount = \(arguments.count)")
    println("theRequest----> \(theRequest)")
    /*.......
    .....*/
    return "OK"
    }
 }
```

when I run my applescript then I get the error (InfoMaker is the name of my app):
    InfoMaker got an error: The handler some object is not defined.

The method :

```
override func application(theApp:NSApplication,delegateHandlesKey theKey:String) -> Bool{ 
    println("scripting key = \(theKey)");
    let thekeys = ["pathToXML", "saveXMLFlag", "webserviceName","methodName","pathToInfoFiles","fileToCheck","scriptingProperties"]

    if thekeys.containsString(theKey.lowercaseString,  searchcase:NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) {
        //[self prefsToVars];
        println("YES")
        return true;
    } else {
        println("NO")
        return false
    }
}
```

in my app delegate responds OK to the applescript.

I tried also with the "SimpleScriptingVerbs" example from Apple and I get the same error in my Swift implementation. I hope somebody can help find the problem and have a suggestion.

Comment: Do you mean that it responds "YES"? That's the `println` in the function.

Answer (score 13):

In the meantime, I was able to find a solution to the problem and get the app working with script commands.

The cocoa class name for your command you must mention in the script definition file (`.sdef`) is not the same as the name of the class in XCode (Swift), as it is the case for Objective-C.

Instead you have to prepend the project name/module to the class like this: `MyProject.MySwiftCommandClassName`

If in doubt what the right name is, in your Swift class, you can use the following code to get the correct name to use in your `.sdef` file:

```
class func classString() -> String {
    return NSStringFromClass(self)
}
```

Your `.sdef` file may look similar to this:

```
<dictionary title="MyAp">
    <suite name="MyAp Suite" code="MyAp" description="MyAp Scripts">
        <command name="myCommand" code="MyApMyCm" description="...">
            <cocoa class="MyProject.MySwiftCommandClassName"/>
            [...]
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. Works for me. Much appreciated!

Comment: Agreed. This just saved me a lot of time.

Comment: This answer got me to my personal breakthrough. My project name has a space in it, which needed to be an underscore _ - your function did it

Comment: I'm not clear about your answer, how you got it to work. Did you use `performDefaultImplementation` or not? Because of the name changes between the question and the answer, I'm not sure that I follow what you did to the function, if anything. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

If you prepend @objc(OrderInfo) to your class definition you won't need to add the project name.

```
@objc(OrderInfo) class OrderInfo : NSScriptCommand {
```